# Load events from db on angular-calendar

Tags: angularjs, arrays, typescript, calendar

I'm trying to load events from database on my calendar view of angular-calendar.. I've made api that gonna return me resources, but I my not succeeding to bind them onto CalendarEvents.. this is part where im trying to do that..  [image]

browser console gives me "undefined" error: [image]

managed to make it work like this but its not adding to an array (well it is but its just switching the one it already added with new one) i mean, i get why but strugle to fix it.. [image]

wonder how could i push to it, or add on index

Comment: You make it easier on answerers when you actually copy code here and don't just take screenshots.

Comment: nvm, fixed it.. thx anyways

Comment: Please edit your question, remove the screenshots and replace them with the actual code as plain, formatted text. [This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1288408) explains why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your code is in a screenshot, I'll show it in pseudo-ish code. Inside your subscribe do the following:

```
this.events = [];
for (let i=0; i<res.data.length; i++) {
    this.events.push({
        title: res.data[i].name,
        start: res.data[i].date,
        color: { ... }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in case any1 needs, somehow made it work.. pushing directly to an orginal array for some reason wont save data into it, so i had to make another one and save data into her when loop is over.. also for it to be not "undefined" and allow me to push to it, it had to be " = [] " (equal to empy array) at beggining..

```
  events: any;
  items: Array<CalendarEvent<{ time: any }>> = [];


this.eventsService.requestEvents().subscribe(res => {
  for(let i=0; i<res.data.length; i++) {
      this.items.push(
      {
        title: res.data[i].name,
        start: new Date(res.data[i].date),
        color: {primary: '#e3bc08', secondary: '#FDF1BA'},
        meta: {
          time: res.data[i].date
        }
    });
    this.events = this.items;
  }
});
```

Comment: gave my best to fix answer.. but dont have old code to coppy old versions too, there is not much of it anyways...